# Specific website is not loading in android web view

Tags: android, webview, android-webview

I am trying to load http://www.bing.com or https://www.bing.com in web view but it is not loading. When I debug I found that the onPageFinished() callback is executed and the web view is still blank.

I have tried with other websites such as http://www.google.com it works fine.

Here is my code

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_web_view);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

    WebView webView = findViewById(R.id.web_view);

    WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webSettings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
    webSettings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewController());
    webView.loadUrl("http://www.bing.com");
}

    public class WebViewController extends WebViewClient {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }
    }
```

In the logs I'm getting the following message when I'm trying to load **bing** website

```
2020-04-10 17:41:31.981 6044-6044/com.mawinbet.android I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "The resource http://www.bing.com/rb/2U/cj,nj/6BsKE-ZQeKe0vHb0vclH0k01aag.js?bu=BUBKDlVY was preloaded using link preload but not used within a few seconds from the window's load event. Please make sure it has an appropriate `as` value and it is preloaded intentionally.", source:  (0)
```

Can you please tell me how to solve this problem.